# How to change axes for component from ruby api

Tags: ruby, sketchup

I have created an Dynamic Component which depend of its options. I need to change axes for component from ruby api. But I can't understand how to do it.

[image: See image]

I tried this way, but it doesn't work out. Any suggestions?

```
selection[0].axes.set(ORIGIN, X_AXIS, Y_AXIS, Z_AXIS)
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: An API call generally sends some JSON to an API endpoint. You need to show what you're sending, what the API expects, and any error messages or outputs that show the response you're currently getting.